# По разному форматируется текст в заголовках DataGrid на разных вкладках TabControl в XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Вот код `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem0">
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                          CanUserSortColumns="False"
                          EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                          HeadersVisibility="Column"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding}"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ti0dgtc1"
                                            Width="*"
                                            Binding="{Binding}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti0dgtc1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Просто такой текст в первом хедере" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ti0dgtc2"
                                            Width="0.8*"
                                            Binding="{Binding}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti0dgtc2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Просто такой текст во втором хедере" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ti0dgtc3" Width="0.5*">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti0dgtc3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Здесь длинный текст в несколько строк в хедере" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ti0dgtc5" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti0dgtc5}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Комментарий" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem1">
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                          CanUserSortColumns="False"
                          EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                          HeadersVisibility="Column"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding}"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ti1dgtc1"
                                            Width="*"
                                            Binding="{Binding}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti1dgtc1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Просто такой текст в первом хедере" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ti1dgtc2"
                                            Width="0.8*"
                                            Binding="{Binding}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti1dgtc2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Просто такой текст во втором хедере" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ti1dgtc3" Width="0.5*">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti1dgtc3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Здесь длинный текст в несколько строк в хедере" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ti1dgtc5" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ti1dgtc5}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Комментарий" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Не пугайтесь такого большого кода. Здесь две вкладки. Во второй вкладке копия первой, только с другими именами колонок.
Для `TextBlock` определил стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

Вот результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, в первой вкладке все нормально отформатировано в заголовках, а во второй нет. Вопрос: почему так и как происходит мне его отформатировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если после запуска приложения обратить внимание на окно Events в VS, то можно увидеть сообщения об ошибках привязки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из текста сообщения, привязка не находит элемент с заданным именем. Это может показаться странным, т. к. элемент с тамим именем, вроде, существует. Но если попробовать в окне Live Visual Tree найти его, то вы его не обнаружите. Дело в том, что TabControl использует виртуализацию и создает контент только по мере необходимости (а необходимость только одна — когда вкладка открыта).

Тут можно, конечно, попробовать как-то отловить момент переключения вкладок и создавать привязку после того как контент отобразится, но это вам скорее всего не нужно, т. к. центрирование текста заголовка столбца DataGrid можно сделать гораздо проще:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Просто такой текст в первом хедере">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и потом стоит вынести этот стиль в ресурсы:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Тогда разметка DataGrid существенно облегчится:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="10*" Header="Просто такой текст в первом хедере"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="8*" Header="Просто такой текст во втором хедере"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="5*" Header="Здесь длинный текст в несколько строк в хедере"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="10*" Header="Комментарий"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]